# Как использовать range js для двух input?

Tags: javascript, input

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь сделать два range слайдера для двух инпутов, но не получается выводить верные значения для каждого инпута. как правильно построить синтаксис?

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('input[id="sum"]');

var rangeValue = function(){
  var newValue = elem.value;
  var target = document.querySelector('.value');
  target.innerHTML = newValue;
}

elem.addEventListener("input", rangeValue);

var elem = document.querySelector('input[id="days"]');

var rangeValue = function(){
  var newValue = elem.value;
  var target = document.querySelector('.value2');
  target.innerHTML = newValue;
}

elem.addEventListener("input", rangeValue);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:700);
body {
  font-family: "Dosis", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  color: #34495e;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-shadow: white 1px 1px 1px;
}
.value {
  border-bottom: 4px dashed #bdc3c7;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10em;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  letter-spacing: -0.07em;
  text-shadow: white 2px 2px 2px;
}
.value2 {
  border-bottom: 4px dashed #bdc3c7;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10em;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  letter-spacing: -0.07em;
  text-shadow: white 2px 2px 2px;
}
input[type="range"] {
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 0;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
​ input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  transform: scale(1.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="value">0</div>
<input type="range" id="sum" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">

<div class="value2">0</div>
<input type="range" id="days" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
```

Благодарен любой помощи!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все оттого, что переменная `elem` - одна и та же. Если для второго слайдера взять другую переменную, то все заработает.

Ниже - измененная часть скрипта для второго слайдера.

```
var elem2 = document.querySelector('input[id="days"]');

var rangeValue = function(){
  var newValue = elem2.value;
  var target = document.querySelector('.value2');
  target.innerHTML = newValue;
}

elem2.addEventListener("input", rangeValue);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evxpme

Когда много таких переменных, то лучше использовать EventListener для дочерних элементов родительского элемента. Тут прекрасная статья - https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm

Comment: Еще бы добавить событие "change" для повышения кроссбраузерности

Comment: Тогда уж проще какой-нибудь плагин для Jquery использовать, там уже все  прописано как надо. Однако их так много, что я не стал включать их в ответ, ограничившись минимальным.

Comment: добавить то там всего лишь одну строку elem2.addEventListener("change", rangeValue);